# How can I compile template class 'Append' from Alexandrescu A. "Modern C++ Design. Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied"?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Alexandrescu in his book implements template class 'Append' for appending a type to a type list in this way:

```
template <class TList, class T> struct Append;

template <> struct Append<NullType, NullType>
{
    typedef NullType Result;
};

template <class T> struct Append<NullType, T>
{
    typedef TYPELIST_1(T) Result;
};

template <class Head, class Tail>
struct Append<NullType, Typelist<Head, Tail> >
{
    typedef Typelist<Head, Tail> Result;
};

template <class Head, class Tail, class T>
struct Append<Typelist<Head, Tail>, T>
{
    typedef Typelist<Head,
        typename Append<Tail, T>::Result>
        Result;
};
```

All 'Append' specializations accept not more than 2 template arguments but the last one accepts 3 template arguments. Trying to compile that code I get the error

```
error C2977: 'Append' : too many template arguments
```

This happens on either msvc compiler or gcc.
Is the 'Append' implementation correct?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with the version of the compilers you are using. There's nothing obviously wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Append` template struct accepts two, and only two arguments: `TList` and `T`.

All other entries are *specializations*, describing a special case, when the value of `T` or `TList` is something special. The last `Append` specialization is for special case where:

- `T` is any type
- `TList` is of a form `Typelist<Head, Tail>` where `Head` and `Tail` are arbitrary type names. I presume `Typelist` is defined somewhere earlier as another 2-argument template.

If you want to create an instance with the last specialization, you will have to use the `Typelist`, e.g.

```
Append< Typelist<char, short>, int> object;
```

(I have chosen `char`, `short`, `int` completely arbitrarily for the sake of the example, and I don't know if it makes sense for the actual `Append` implementation)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have thought a compiler can deduce the 3rd 'Append' specialization by 3 arguments but it's only a trick to traverse first two arguments to 'TypeList' specialization